# Where should one go for Magento Support?

Tags: discussion

After migrating from stackoverflow.com/tags/magento and the old community forum at magento.com, it seems that we are now left with two separate and capable forums for Magento support:

https://magento.stackexchange.com/
&&
http://community.magento.com/t5/Programming-Questions/bd-p/devqa

My questions are:
Which forum should be in primary use?
Is there any advantage of one forum over the other?
Are certain types of questions better suited on either forum?
Is there a different visitor persona on either forum or are they similar?
How about engagement levels?

Also if anyone could compile a list of awesome Magento support resources delineated by user experience and role that could be super helpful.

---

Magento community forums are also very focused on technical issues. See list of forum categories:

[image: Magento Community Forum Cats]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The charter of this site, and why it merits its own site apart from Stackoverflow, [is that we encourage less technical questions](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/294/user-application-questions), e.g., those about admin panel functionality, that would not be tolerated on SO. However, all questions on this site must still have canonical answers. This is a Q&A site first and foremost.

If an answer can only be opinion based, such as your question above, it should either be asked here in Meta, or more appropriately, directed to the Magento Community Forums. The forums provide a better venue for extended discussion that can go deeper than pure Q&A.

Comment: I like how you differentiate the forums by format rather than technical vs non.

Comment: As the originator of this site, I'm 100% behind this answer. `HaveAWorthlessMetaUpvote.gif`

Answer (score 1):

For a list of resources check out https://github.com/aleron75/mageres by Alessandro Ronchi.

This forums primary focus is technical questions. All others are better off on the community.magento.com forum